# inconsistent behavior when using read or write parquette with pyarrow or without

Tags: python-polars

I just tried to write and read from a parquet file.

What i discovered is that based on the tried out combination, i should declare use_pyarrow=True on df.write_parquet, but false when reading for maximum performance.

If both are false ,reading the parquet is slower. Is this a bug?

Code to reproduce:

```
import time
import polars as pl
import numpy as np


df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        f"{i}": np.random.randint(0, 120, size=3000000,)
        for i in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 'I', "J", 'K',)
    }
)


def repeat_read(arrow_read: bool, arrow_write: bool, n_times: int = 25) -> float:
    df.write_parquet('parquet', use_pyarrow=arrow_write)

    timings = []
    for i in range(n_times):
        time_start = time.time()
        some_var = pl.read_parquet('parquet', use_pyarrow=arrow_read)
        timings.append(time.time() - time_start)
    return sum(timings) / len(timings)

for i in range(3):
    print(f"Run {i}")
    read_write_false = repeat_read(arrow_read=False, arrow_write=False)
    print(f"Read-Write False: {read_write_false}")

    read_write_true = repeat_read(arrow_read=True, arrow_write=True)
    print(f"Read-Write Truee: {read_write_true}")

    read_false_write_true = repeat_read(arrow_read=False, arrow_write=True)
    print(f"Read False, Write True: {read_false_write_true}")

    read_true_write_false = repeat_read(arrow_read=True, arrow_write=False)
    print(f"Read True, Write False: {read_true_write_false}")
    print('---------------------------------------------------------\n')
```

Outcome:

```
Read-Write False: 0.11888686180114746
Read-Write Truee: 0.14296542167663573
Read False, Write True: 0.07793953895568848
Read True, Write False: 0.16698485374450683
```

The interesting thing is that while the performance boost still persists, it has diminishing returns when 'x' is equal to size in randint(0, x, size=1000000)

Comment: Why would different execution times be a bug? Those are different implementations.

Comment: Isn't use_pyarrow=True or False generating the same file structure? I though this variable is just about the backend to use to generate this file thus the write might be slower, but i didn't understand why the read is slower as well. 

From your answer i sense that this is not the case and it's a completely different format although both create an IPC file?